# puedo convertir este String a un objeto iterable con javascript

Tags: javascript

Hola necesito convertir este  String  a un objeto iterable con javascript
para recorrerlo y extraer la info como sería la mejor forma de hacerlo. Gracias

```js
const data = "[{
        "name": "sony",
        "id": "14272",
        "phone": 12345687,
        "description": "Horario: 9:00-17:30"

    },
    {
        "name": "Huawey",
        "id": "5846",
        "phone": 245874895,
        "description": "Horario: 12:00-14:40"
    },
    {
        "name": "Panasonic",
        "id": 14855151,
        "phone": 3458874595,
        "description": "Horario: 10:25-17:55"

    }
]";

console.log(JSON.parse(data))
```

Comment: Ese array de objetos ya es algo iterable, considera leer [ask], editar y mostrar que llevas para evitar el cierre de tu publicación

Comment: no, es un string y no se puede iterar

Comment: Entonces colocalo como corresponde por que como te digo eso es un array y si es iterable

Comment: si ahí lo edité

Comment: perdon es mi primera publicación, gracias por la correción. he intentando con JSON.stringify() y JSON.parse()

Comment: Lo que has intentado debe ir dentro del código de la pregunta. Es muy probable que exista algún error en él y la solución sea simple. Por favor entra a [edit] e incluye el código que intentaste usar y falló.

Comment: @BetaM tiene razón cuando usas `JSON.parse(data);` ya es iterable, el único problema que se ve de forma clara es que debes usar comilla invertida en lugar de comilla doble en la cadena JSON que muestras.

Comment: @Israel-ICM Mi comentario fue antes de que el OP le añadiera las comillas, por lo demás ya no estoy siguiendo la pregunta por lo que le expuse en el primer comentario

Answer (score 1):

Cambia la primera y última comilla `"` por "backticks" `` ` `` y usa `JSON.parse()`. Así:

```
const data = `[{
        "name": "sony",
        "id": "14272",
        "phone": 12345687,
        "description": "Horario: 9:00-17:30"

    },
    {
        "name": "Huawey",
        "id": "5846",
        "phone": 245874895,
        "description": "Horario: 12:00-14:40"
    },
    {
        "name": "Panasonic",
        "id": 14855151,
        "phone": 3458874595,
        "description": "Horario: 10:25-17:55"

    }
]`;
```

El problema es que tu variable no consiste en una sola string, si no que consiste en varias strings entre símbolos. Por ejemplo (Voy a usar solo el inicio):

```
const data = "[{
        "name": "sony",
```

Para el intérprete es:

```
const data = "[{" //<=Declaracion de variable data y asignación a la string:"[{"
name//<= Variable "name"???
": "//<=String
```

Te dejo el snippet para que veas que si funciona:

```js
const data = `[{
        "name": "sony",
        "id": "14272",
        "phone": 12345687,
        "description": "Horario: 9:00-17:30"

    },
    {
        "name": "Huawey",
        "id": "5846",
        "phone": 245874895,
        "description": "Horario: 12:00-14:40"
    },
    {
        "name": "Panasonic",
        "id": 14855151,
        "phone": 3458874595,
        "description": "Horario: 10:25-17:55"

    }
]`;

console.log(JSON.parse(data))
```

Último recurso:

```js
const data = "[{ \"name\": \"sony\", \"id\": \"14272\", \"phone\": 12345687, \"description\": \"Horario: 9:00-17:30\" }, { \"name\": \"Huawey\", \"id\": \"5846\", \"phone\": 245874895, \"description\": \"Horario: 12:00-14:40\" }, { \"name\": \"Panasonic\", \"id\": 14855151, \"phone\": 3458874595, \"description\": \"Horario: 10:25-17:55\" } ]";

console.log(JSON.parse(data))
```

Comment: Me arroja error igual  VM8599:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ` in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: Añadí el snippet para que veas que sí funciona. Asegurate de estar usando ` y no  ' . Mira como en el snippet también se marca toda la string en verde.

Comment: Veo que en el error que obtienes toma como el primer objeto una ` ¿Podría ser que estás usando dos backticks en vez de uno? Tiene que ser `, si pones dos está incorrecto. `` Está mal

Comment: no, esta bien la sintaxis. Si lo ejecuto acá no da problemas pero en mi local me levanta ese error

Comment: Que extraño, te edite la respuesta con una última solución, es lo único que se me ocurre.

Comment: Ahí lo solucioné. Estaba sucediendo que partes de contenidos del String tenían espacios que tiraban error en el parseo. Gracias FranAcuna